# Database diagram connectors (SSMS 2012)

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, ssms

When creating a SSMS database diagram, I can click and drag to link two columns together. I can also move the connectors along the edges of the diagram.

The problem is that SSMS places the connectors table-to-table instead of column-to-column. This makes it hard to indicate at-a-glance exactly which columns are being linked, and if I place the connectors manually, they all get rearranged if I move the table. Is there any way to "snap" the connector to a column, or even any location on the table diagram?

Comment: It's pretty annoying isn't it. So many features in ssms are really well thought out, unfortunately this one isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe the database diagram connectors in SSMS work this way, but you can request/suggest new features here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback